Boto3 v1.34.104 in AWS Lambda wont allow passing variables parameter in codepipeline.start_pipeline_execution
I was trying to update a lambda I have which triggers code pipeline whenever there is a change in the code. Its based on top of AWS SAM Template pipeline code for monorepo. I was modifying it to become a single handler which triggers the SAM deployment for all child repos of the mono repo rather than having a separate function for each child repo. For this the final piece that connects it all together is passing arguments to code pipeline via boto3. I was able to see from boto3 v1.34.104 that it supports passing argument to code pipeline while calling the codepipelineclient.start_pipeline_execution. However when I did the same it gave me the following error when testing the lambda on AWS
{
  "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nUnknown parameter in input: \"variables\", must be one of: name, clientRequestToken",
  "errorType": "ParamValidationError",
  "requestId": "2b719927-3f77-47db-a555-406f50f5fd92",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/opt/python/aws_lambda_powertools/logging/logger.py\", line 354, in decorate\n    return lambda_handler(event, context, *args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/index.py\", line 23, in lambda_handler\n    start_codepipeline(pipeline_name, [\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/index.py\", line 39, in start_codepipeline\n    code_pipeline.start_pipeline_execution(name=codepipeline_name, variables=[{'name': 'Test', 'value': 'VariableValue'}])\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/botocore/client.py\", line 565, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/botocore/client.py\", line 974, in _make_api_call\n    request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/botocore/client.py\", line 1048, in _convert_to_request_dict\n    request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/botocore/validate.py\", line 381, in serialize_to_request\n    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())\n"
  ]
}

I have the following code and I was able to verify that through a lambda layer I have I am running boto3 v1.34.104.
Logs for that:
{"level":"INFO","location":"lambda_handler:20","message":{"boto3 Version":"1.34.104","botocore Version":"1.34.105"},"timestamp":"2024-05-15 08:17:36,034+0000",

Here is a snippet of the code:
import os, boto3
from aws_lambda_powertools.logging import Logger
from aws_lambda_powertools.utilities import parameters
import botocore

logger = Logger()
cc = boto3.client('codecommit')
code_pipeline = boto3.client('codepipeline')
ssm = boto3.client('ssm')
ssm_prefix = os.environ.get('SSM_PREFIX', '')
pipeline_name = os.environ.get('PIPELINE_NAME')
@logger.inject_lambda_context
def lambda_handler(event, _):
    commit_id = event['detail']['commitId']
    branch_name = event['detail']['referenceName']
    repository = event['detail']['repositoryName']
    paths = get_modified_files_since_last_run(repository, commit_id, branch_name)
    toplevel_dirs = get_unique_toplevel_dirs(paths)
    logger.info({'boto3 Version': boto3.__version__, 'botocore Version': botocore.__version__ })
    logger.info({'paths': paths, 'toplevel_dirs': toplevel_dirs, 'pipeline_name': pipeline_name})
    start_codepipeline(pipeline_name, [
        {
            'name': 'ProjectSubfolders',
            'value': toplevel_dirs
        },
    ])
    update_last_commit(repository, commit_id, branch_name)
def get_unique_toplevel_dirs(modified_files):
    toplevel_dirs = set(filter(lambda a: len(a) > 1, [file.split('/')[0] for file in modified_files]))
    logger.info('toplevel dirs: %s', toplevel_dirs)
    return list(toplevel_dirs)
def start_codepipeline(codepipeline_name, additional_vars):
    logger.info('Additional vars are: %s', additional_vars)
    try:
        # THIS LINE THROWS THE ERROR
        code_pipeline.start_pipeline_execution(name=codepipeline_name, variables=additional_vars)
        logger.info(f'Started CodePipeline {codepipeline_name}.')
    except code_pipeline.exceptions.PipelineNotFoundException:
        logger.info(f'Could not find CodePipeline {codepipeline_name}.')
        return False
    return True

...(helper functions which I believe are unrelated because boto3 throws the error at the marked line)

Thankyou for any help anyone could provide to what could be possible issues here.
I tried with 1.34.105 and 1.34.104 for boto3 layers, but since the boto version appears to be accurate Im not sure what could be the issue here. The error persists even if the variables argument is hardcoded to some other value like variables=[{'name': 'Test', 'value': 'VariableValue'}]
